# vuforia-unity virtual button enabling or disabling teapot

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have created virtual button in Unity-Vuforia by following tutorial. It works successfully without any glitch.
The problem is I tried to enable or disable teapot upon press or release. I have tried the following code for changing materials:

```
public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb)
{
    Debug.Log("OnButtonPressed: " + vb.VirtualButtonName);

    if (!IsValid())
    {
        return;
    }

    // Add the material corresponding to this virtual button
    // to the active material list:
    switch (vb.VirtualButtonName)
    {
        case "red":
            mActiveMaterials.Add(m_TeapotMaterials[0]);
            break;

        case "blue":
            mActiveMaterials.Add(m_TeapotMaterials[1]);
            break;

        case "yellow":
            mActiveMaterials.Add(m_TeapotMaterials[2]);
            break;

        case "green":
            mActiveMaterials.Add(m_TeapotMaterials[3]);
            break;
    }

    // Apply the new material:
    if (mActiveMaterials.Count > 0)
        mTeapot.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = mActiveMaterials[mActiveMaterials.Count - 1];
}

/// <summary>
/// Called when the virtual button has just been released:
/// </summary>
public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb)
{
    if (!IsValid())
    {
        return;
    }

    // Remove the material corresponding to this virtual button
    // from the active material list:
    switch (vb.VirtualButtonName)
    {
        case "red":
            mActiveMaterials.Remove(m_TeapotMaterials[0]);
            break;

        case "blue":
            mActiveMaterials.Remove(m_TeapotMaterials[1]);
            break;

        case "yellow":
            mActiveMaterials.Remove(m_TeapotMaterials[2]);
            break;

        case "green":
            mActiveMaterials.Remove(m_TeapotMaterials[3]);
            break;
    }

    // Apply the next active material, or apply the default material:
    if (mActiveMaterials.Count > 0)
        mTeapot.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = mActiveMaterials[mActiveMaterials.Count - 1];
    else
        mTeapot.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = m_TeapotMaterials[4];
}
#endregion //PUBLIC_METHODS
```

Somebody could point me how will I enable.teapot.gameobject upon 'red'button pressed and disable teapot gameobject upon 'red' button released?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to have a reference to your teapot gameobject. So at the top where you declare your variables add this:

```
public GameObject teaPotGameObject;
```

Assign teapot to this slot in the inspector. Then in the OnButtonPressed() function after `case "red":` add this line:

```
teaPotGameObject.SetActive(true);
```

And well, I guess you already know what to do in OnButtonReleased() function :))

Comment: thank you very much. I did everything as you explained. the app is crashing after executing first time correctly.

Comment: it's working. I removed it's default actions which was interfering. now it's working perfectly. thanks